# docker containers won't connect to DNS server container

Tags: linux, linux-networking, docker

I am using docker 1.7.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with kernel 3.13.0-55. Docker is started using the options

> DOCKER_OPTS="--bip=172.17.42.1/24 --dns=172.17.42.1 --dns=8.8.8.8"

to ensure a fixed ip range for containers. I want to use a container as DNS server for all of the other containers (see the dns config option above). I therefore started my DNS container with a port binding to 172.17.42.1:53/udp:

`$ docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.PortBindings}}' mydns
map[53/udp:[{172.17.42.1 53}]]`

I can query the DNS server from my host using the ip *172.17.42.1*, but can't from inside of any of the containers:

`$ nslookup some-host 172.17.42.1
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

I tried to explicitly allow this with iptables as follows

`iptables -A INPUT -s 172.17.42.1 -d 172.17.42.1 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT`

but it still doesn't work.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

[Edit]
This is the result of a DNS query issued from a container captured by tcpdump and visualized by Wireshark:

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe run a network trace?

Comment: @PedroPerez I added a visualization of the trace, is that what you meant?

Comment: yes, thanks. Seems that the container could resolve 172.17.42.1 to the correct MAC address and put the query out, but you might want to tweak your iptables rule based on what's shown on the capture: The DNS request comes from 172.17.42.10 and not .1; not sure this will fix the issue, but if it doesn't you'll have to capture inside the DNS container probably (and enable some logging on the DNS service and maybe iptables)

Comment: @PedroPerez you were right, I just used the wrong source IP for the iptables rule. Thank you so much, you saved my day :)

Comment: The truth is always *on the wire* ;) glad to help!